# Ionic modal popup is not working

Tags: ionic-framework

I just have started working on ionic version 1 and added a code to open modal  and it is not opening up any modal. it is giving me this error:- "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND". Below are my code:-

```
  // Load the modal from the given template URL
        $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('pages/modal/memberid/memberid.html', {
      scope: $scope,
      animation: 'slide-in-up'
   }).then(function(modal) {
      $scope.modal = modal;
   });

   $scope.openModal = function() {
      $scope.modal.show();
   };

   $scope.closeModal = function() {
      $scope.modal.hide();
   };

   //Cleanup the modal when we're done with it!
   $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
      $scope.modal.remove();
   });

   // Execute action on hide modal
   $scope.$on('modal.hidden', function() {
      // Execute action
   });

   // Execute action on remove modal
   $scope.$on('modal.removed', function() {
      // Execute action
   });
   $ionicModal.show();
```

I have created a html file inside of my www/pages/modal/memberid/memberid.html folder:-. it is showing an error regarding the template file not found

Answer (score 2):

The filepath that you are specifying is incorrect just try to resolve it using browser first.

---

as an alternate solution you can try to use embedded template on html itself

```
 <script id="modal.html" type="text/ng-template">some modal code</script>
```

and use `modal.html` as url in your javascript

Comment: where to add the above script?

Comment: you can add it in html page where you have specified controller

Comment: I was using wrong path "id="templates/wapFeedModal.html", 
id="wapFeedModal.html" worked for me.